Removing Server header from IIS 10 for static content
How can I remove Server header for static content (e.g. javascript/css/images) that is server by ASP.NET Web Forms application that is hosted on IIS 10? I think I tried pretty much everything that I found and I still cannot get rid of it. Currently, I have:

removeServerHeader="true" for requestFiltering:

<security><requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true">...

Managed modules enabled for all requests:

<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">...

Removed header in custom headers:

<httpProtocol> <customHeaders>      <remove name="Server"/>

URL rewrite rule:
 <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
     <rule name="Remove RESPONSE_Server" >
         <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+" />
         <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
     </rule>
 </outboundRules>


And even Apache 2.4 reverse proxy with headers module enabled:


LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

...

<IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader unset Server
</IfModule>```


> And I still get Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 added to static file
> responses. Please let me know what I am missing here or if there is
> anything else I can do to get rid of this header.


As far as I know, the Url Rewrite doesn't remove the server variable, it just leaves it blank.
In most cases we can remove server headers via the property removeServerHeader in IIS. Here I found that you have edited the following properties in web.config:
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true">
    <!-- other request filtering stuff -->
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>

This is to remove the server header at the site level.
I recommend that you do the following at the server level as well.

Open IIS and Double-click the Configuration Editor


paste the following into the section dropdown: system.webServer/security/requestFiltering


Set removeServerHeader to True




Thank you for your response! Leaving server header blank would suffice for me, however I cannot achieve even that. I tried to remove server header at IIS level as you suggested, however it still displays server header for static content. Also, tried creating outbound url rewrite rule at IIS level and that didn't help either

Have you tried to use this registry item DisableServerHeader? mentioned in this blog: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers/ba-p/369710
